# Easy ways to solve

Tags: rubiks-cube

I learned how to solve a rubik's cube this summer. On my first try (after memorizing all the algorithms) I got a sub-50. Now, my personal best is 31 seconds. I tried learning the Fridrich method but I don't ever have the time to sit and watch a tutorial. I use the beginners method. Though sometimes I do 1-look instead of 2. Any ways on how to get faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to improve your times you should learn F2L. 
I guess you also mean the same thing with Fridrich (althought F2L is only the second step of Fridrich).

You can learn it by watching a tutorial and by practicing a lot. And don't come with the excuse of not having time. If you don't have time watching a 10 minute tutorial you also have no time on practicing the cube and you'll not achieve your goal of getting faster. There is no magic trick, that improves your times without effort.

You can learn F2L from here: [How To Learn F2L Intuitively](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PkaWYMoVoM). The video is not only 9 minutes long. Although you probably will take much longer to get used to the idea of F2L and it will take a few weeks until you get good times with it. At first your solving time will skyrocket. But don't give up! If you practice a lot, you'll get used to all the different cases and you'll be faster than ever.

And from time to time you should learn a few 1-look cases. Quite a lot of them are really easy (especially the OLLs). For instance you probably know the alg `F (R U R' U') F'`. Another OLL is `F (R U R' U')2 F'` (the middle term is executed twice). Or another one is `Fw (R U R' U')2 Fw'` (take the first to layers of F instead of only one).